# Sencha touch build error when native packaging for ios !AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

When i try to package my application natively for IOS  in Sencha Touch 2.1 it gives me this error:

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[ERR]       
!AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication
The application was successfully packaged
The application was successfuly signed
[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 1
```

It's not working with Xcode please any help will be appreciated.

This is my `packager.json`

```
{
"applicationName":"Demoedifarm",
"applicationId":"com.palapa.demoedifarm",
"bundleSeedId":"S5583Y6VFB",
"versionString":"1.0",
//"versionCode":"1",
"icon": {
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"
},
"inputPath":"./",
"outputPath":"../build/",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"iOS",
"deviceType":"iPad",
"certificateAlias":"iPhone Developer",
//"certificatePassword":"",
"provisionProfile":"/Users/palapa1/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/CA412FD2-60D6-407E-B7AD-A34637A8FF55.mobileprovision",
//"sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdk",
//"sdkPath":"/path/to/android-sdk",
//"androidAPILevel":"8",
/*"permissions":[
                "INTERNET",
                "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
                "CAMERA",
                "VIBRATE",
                "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
                "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
                "CALL_PHONE"],*/
"minOSVersion": "4.2.1",
"orientations": [
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight"

]
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, just curious as to whether you ever figured out the fix to this problem?

Comment: Hi Thomas no i never did i went with phonegap to package my application

Comment: What command are you using to package the app?

Comment: sencha package run packager.json i think thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running a more recent version of Sencha Cmd (3.1), and I believe the command syntax has changed slightly, but I hit this same error so I figured I'd put an answer out just in case it helps someone.

If I run the following command:

`sencha app package run myConfigFile.json`

Then it fails with the same error, and I don't know what the problem is. However if I change the config file so it is targeting the iOS Simulator (the 'platform' property) then it works fine (the simulator opens automatically).

If I run this command instead:

`sencha app package build myConfigFile.json`

Then it completes successfully, and I end up with a MyApp.app file in the output folder.

If I have the XCode Organizer window open, I can then drag this file onto the 'Applications' folder underneath my attached phone and it will deploy/install the app for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a provisioning profile you need to set

```
"configuration":"Release"
```

instead of `Debug` in `packager.json`. That's a [bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273705-Small-bug-in-the-native-packaging-docs) in the docs.

Also, see this post for a good tutorial: http://frightanic.com/software-development/sencha-touch-native-packaging-for-ios-done-right/